# How to hide all the app icons installed in android except setting and my installed app icon

Tags: android

I'm trying to make an app which would have this function that when i install this app only on tablet device then all the apps icon installed before my app on that tablet got hide. the main screen should look like that only my app icon and setting icon is shown on screen.
I used the following code but it only hiding my app icon not others. Can I do this or not ? if I can then help me for this. here is the code

```html
 PackageManager p = getPackageManager();
        ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName
                (this, com.example.junaidsaif.skyhighreward.MainScreen.class); // activity which is first time open in manifiest file which is declare as <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        p.setComponentEnabledSetting(componentName, PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
```

please help me for this

Comment: for that you have to create custom launcher

Comment: is there any other option ?

Comment: I don't think so because you can hide your app icon only for hiding other icons mobile phone must be rooted

Comment: The launcher is who shows the app icons and launch them so its the only who can decide where to show them or not.

Comment: ok Sir. Thanks a lot